# Why does my Eclipse formatter move the condition and parenthesis to separate lines for my if statements and for loops?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, if-statement, format

When I reformat my java code in Eclipse (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>), it does weird things to my if statements. It puts the open parenthesis, the condition, and the closing parenthesis each on their own line.

Here is an example:

```
        if (
            x != null
        )
        {
          ...
        }
```

I want it to look like this:

```
        if (x != null)
        {
          ...
        }
```

Reformatting does the same thing to my for loops:

```
    for (
            int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++
    )
    {
       ...
    }
```

I've tried going to *Window -> Preferences -> Code Style -> Formatter*. I can't find the option I need in order to fix this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The option you're looking for is in the place you said (Code Style -> Formatter). It's in the section `Parentheses positions`, and the option you're looking for is called `'if', 'while' and 'do while' statement:` and `'for' statement:`. You've got them set to `Separate lines`. Revert them back to the default value of `Same line as content`.

Comment: I went to the place rzwitserloot suggested. They are already set to "Same line as content".  I wonder if Eclipse is for some reason not actually using these formatting settings. I have clicked on "Apply" and restarted the program. It didn't help.

Comment: A project can have its own formatter settings. Right click on a project, pick properties.. - there's a codestyle - formatter option here as well.

Comment: Yes! The project had its own formatter settings. Thank you!